# filter duplicate of one column of data but show all the data from another column

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, duplicates

i am doing mvc3 and linQ
i have the database like this

```
class    student        gender

A        john           Male
B        George         Male
A        bill           Female
A        Steve          Male
```

how do i code to filter the duplicate as the result as below

```
A
John       male
bill       female
steve      male

B
George     male
```

i have tried method A

```
  var bb = from bbb in unitOfWork.Checklists
                     orderby bbb.class
                     select bbb;
```

and also method B

```
        var group = (from p in unitOfWork.Checklists
                     group p by p.class into g
                     select new Checklists
                     {
                         class= g.Key,
                          name= g.ToString()
                     }).AsEnumerable();
```

but all failed~
Any idea for this ? This is breaking my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use ObjectDumper project in the visual studio C# sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace testLinq
{
    public class Record
    {
        public string ClassName {get;set;}
        public string Student {get;set;}
        public string Gender {get;set;}


    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Record[] list = new Record[] { 
                new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="john" , Gender="male" },
                new Record { ClassName="B" , Student="George" , Gender="male" },
                new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="bill" , Gender="Female" },
                new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="Steve" , Gender="male" }
            };

            var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ClassName).Select(x => new { k = x.Key, person = x});

            ObjectDumper.Write(result, 1);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Hello World!
k=A     person=...
  person: ClassName=A     Student=john    Gender=male
  person: ClassName=A     Student=bill    Gender=Female
  person: ClassName=A     Student=Steve   Gender=male
k=B     person=...
  person: ClassName=B     Student=George  Gender=male
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Example MVC code

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        Record[] list = new Record[] { 
            new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="john" , Gender="male" },
            new Record { ClassName="B" , Student="George" , Gender="male" },
            new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="bill" , Gender="Female" },
            new Record { ClassName="A" , Student="Steve" , Gender="male" }
        };

        var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ClassName).Select(x => new { k = x.Key, person = x});
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            ObjectDumper.Write(result, 1 , writer);
            pivotString = writer.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string pivotString;

    public string PivotTableText { get { return pivotString; } }
}

public static class YourHtmlExtension
{
    public static string EncodedMultiLineText(this HtmlHelper helper, string text) 
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
      {
        return String.Empty;
      }
      return Regex.Replace(helper.Encode(text), Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
    public ActionResult ReadPivotTable()
    {
        return View((new YourViewModel());
    }
```

In your view

```
<%= Html.EncodedMultiLineText(Model.PivotTableText) %>
```

Comment: LinqPad is a great tool to test linq

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that ObjectDumper seems cannot use at mvc3 ? this is because i am using in mvc3. do u have the code with mvc3? appreciated :)

Comment: thanks, i done the thing in another way already, the code seems not applicate in mvc3, anyway, thanks for the help, but i think that can be applicate in mvc2, so i mark it as answer, if anyone got any idea welcome edit this post in order to help more people

Answer (score 1):

**class** is a keyword in C# and I you can't use as property names. You need a group by and probably you need either to create a wrapper class to pass the result

```
from p in unitOfWork.Checklists
group p by p.Class into groupByClass
select new
{
   Class= groupByClass.Key,
   Students = groupByClass
}
```

Comment: that code i tried before, not working for me, i also not sure why

Comment: I saw a previous question of you with the same problem. I think you don't understand that when you do Select new {g.Key, g} g.Key is actually the property used between "by" and "into" , this case p.Class and g is a COLLECTION of the corresponding items to the g.Key. So when you do data binding with a collection you need to  iterate through that collection.